# Getting the visible text of an element

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

This is a very simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer to it, because documentation for the javascript bindings of selenium-webdriver are so sparse. (There's plenty of documentation for the java bindings, but javascript is another story)

Assuming `driver` and `webdriver` as they are normally instanatiated, how do I get the text of an arbitrary element?

I've tried an incredible number of combinations of getText(), then(), etc., but nothing I do seems to work.  I must be doing something completely wrong.

Comment: Are you writing your tests in javascript, or just wanting to execute some javascript from within your tests (written in Java/C#/something else)?

Comment: My tests are written in javascript.  I'm using Mocha, Chai, and selenium-webdriver (on Node.js).

Comment: Does `element.getAttribute("innerText")` give you element text?

Comment: Couldn't get it to work.  I tried these variations:
   `console.log(driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('html')).getAttribute("innerText"));`   `driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('html')).then(function(v) { console.log(v.getAttribute("innerText")); });`

Comment: Not sure of JS bindings...but can you check if the element is displayed using "isDisplayed" method.

Comment: GetAttribute('value') should work for input elements

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, I found the following similar (working) bit of code in another test in my test suite.  It's odd to me that I was able to get the other test (below) working, but not the one I've been focusing on.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.failures em')).getText().then(function(v) {
    expect(v).to.equal('0');
    done();
});
```

Perhaps I was overlooking something else.

Regardless, I've become too frustrated with selenium-webdriver's confusing mix of synchronous/asynchronous code with Promises and the like.  I've decided to move to using WebdriverJS (http://www.webdriver.io/) instead, and so far, have found the migration highly intuitive and satisfying.  Testing is fun again! :)

Best of luck!

Comment: 2017 Update: You may also want to check out PhantomJS and NightmareJS depending on what your needs are